# How to debug Ruby symbols?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am working on the JavaScript side of a Ruby app, but every once in a while I have to dip into the code.  I am trying to figure out what a certain symbol does.

In Haml, I have this code:

```
%footer.media-footer
          %strong
            %small
              = link_to "Edit", polymorphic_path([:edit, comment.commentable, comment]), rel: "edit nofollow", style: "display: none", remote: true, method: :get, data: { type: "text html" }
```

I am trying to figure out to what `:edit` is and what permissions are being allowed in `polymorphic_path`.  I put a `pry` statement in the Haml code, but I couldn't find any information with that.

How do I chase this down?  What should be my next step?

Comment: You don't debug symbols. Think of them as string literals for this use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is more or less the same as if you want to debug the string `'edit'`.

Though symbols are not the same as string, they behave like them, but they have a semantic connotation, meaning that the content means their value

Answer (score 0):

The symbol doesn't contain any internal code or state - it's just a series of letters. What you need to look at is what the function is doing with its arguments - in this case, what is `polymorphic_path` doing with its arguments?

You should be able to find the answer in [the `polymorphic_url` documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_url).